# Automatically switching ftp connection with openPDC

Tags: c#, sql-server, ftp, pdc

Background, we use openPDC as an ftp to transfer files from various partners. Some partners have multiple clone servers, for example server 1, 2, and 3 (some partners only have 2 servers, some have more). They all produce the exact same files, deleting them after a time if not picked up. Normally we only pull from server 1, however sometimes they'll bring it down for maintenance or whatever, and we manually change the connection info to server 2 or 3. We have the connection data for all 3, so we'd like to automatically cycle through the available connections should one fail. I suggested just pulling from all the connections and deleting duplicate files, but management doesn't want to waste the bandwidth.

[image: openPDC Manager screen]

Everything here is stored in a sql server. There are 2 things we need here, connection string and ID Code(Access ID). Connection string is stored in sql as a string, and parsed into a dictionary for use with C#. As I understand it there's already some support for switching there and if not it shouldn't be too hard to implement. The trickier part is the ID Code. It is stored in sql as an int, and is utilized as an int data type in C#. It can be anywhere from 1-99999, so I can't convert to a string and try to use 5 character chunks. According to a file search it's used 386 times in the project across dll, sql, cs, xml, cshtml, and more file types, many of which I have no experience with. If I actually try to change the data type then I'll have to look at all of them and probably change most of them.

If you could offer any alternative solution, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Unfortunately this is far too broad for SO and therefore off-topic. This site is focused on answering technical questions, not providing "solutions".

Comment: See the configuration file on page 34 (https://www.nrel.gov/docs/fy13osti/56610.pdf).  You would have to change the configuration file.